# $xy=22$ and $yz=26$: What is $x+y+z $ equal to?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, problem-solving

Given the following: $$xy=22,\qquad yz=26,$$ where $x,y,z\in\mathbb{N}$. Which of the following is a possible value of $ x + y + z $?

$ \textbf {(A) } 22 \qquad \textbf {(B) } 24 \qquad \textbf {(C) } 26 \qquad \textbf {(D) } 48 $

Comment: What should I do with my choice?

Comment: @abiessu - The question was formulated like that. Your answer must be one of the 4 choices..

Comment: @Hilbert I think that abiessu is commenting on the tone of the question, not the statement itself. Please note that stating such a question in a very imperative tone is frequently taken to be rude here.

Comment: Hilbert, please show us what you have attempted.

Comment: @AhaanRungta - I tried at first to solve it algebraic but didn't succeed. When i began to put numbers and "guessing" the answer..

Answer (score 10):

**Hint**: There aren't very many choices for $x, y, z$. In fact, since $22 = 2 \cdot 11$ and $22 = 1 \cdot 22$ are the only ways to break up $22$ as multiplication, we see that

$$x, y \in \{1, 2, 11, 22\}$$

On the other hand,

$$y, z \in \{1, 2, 13, 26\}$$

Combining these shows that $y \in \{1, 2\}$. Now consider cases based on this.

Answer (score 5):

We know that $(x+z)y=48$. We are looking for $(x+z)+y$.
$$
x+z=1;y=48\implies (x+z)+y=49\\
x+z=2;y=24\implies (x+z)+y=26\\
x+z=3;y=16\implies (x+z)+y=19\\
x+z=4;y=12\implies (x+z)+y=16\\
x+z=6;y=8\implies (x+z)+y=14\\
$$
we could switch the values, and get the other choices, but the sums and products remain the same.

The only common element is $26$.

If we want the actual values, note that $(x+z)y=2\cdot24$. Since neither $xy=22$ nor $yz=26$ are divisible by $24$, we need $y=2$. Then we get $x=11$ and $z=13$.

Comment: IMHO, your answer is really misleading for solving such a problem.

Comment: @user104254: Why is that? We are given $(x+z)y=48$  and some values of $(x+z)+y$. The only one which matches is $26$ coming from the factorization $48=2\cdot24$. This means either that $x+z=2$ and $y=24$ or that $x+z=24$ and $y=2$. Since neither $xy=22$ nor $yz=26$ are divisible by $24$, $y\ne24$, that leaves $x+z=24$ and $y=2$. Thus, $xy=22\implies x=11$ and $yz=26\implies z=13$.

Comment: Igoring $xy=a$ and $yz=b$ and focusing on $y(x+z)=ab$ abandons the important information $y\mid \gcd(a,b)$ and increaes the workload by producing lots of fake solutions of $x+y+z$ to check.

Answer (score 1):

Look at $xy$ divisors  and $yz$ divisors. (Because we have that $x,y,z \in \mathbb{N}$.)

$$
\begin{array}{|c|lcr|}
\hline xy \text{ and } yz & \text{} \\
\hline
22 & 1 & 2 & 11 & 22 \\
26 & 1 & 2 & 13 & 26 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

So if $xy=22=\color{red}{2}\cdot11 = \color{green}{1} \cdot 22$, and $yz=26=\color{red}{2}\cdot13 = \color{green}{1} \cdot 26$

then $y$ is either $\color{red}{2}$ or $\color{green}{1}$ and nothing else. We can do an easy shortcut: In the possibilities, we only have even numbers. $(1)$

So $y$ cannot be equal to $1$ since it would imply that $x+y+z$ is odd in contradiction with $(1)$. 
But $x+y+z$ will be even if $y = 2$, so: $x+y+z=11+2+13=26$

Therefore the right answer is: $\boxed{\textbf{(C) } 26}$

Answer (score 0):

**Shortcut.** Since both given products are even, we can just assume that $y$ is even, so let it be $y=2$. Then, $x=11$ and $z=13$. Then, $$x+y+z=11+2+13=\boxed{\textbf{(C) } 26}.$$

Comment: What do you mean with "Since both given products are equal"? The first one is 22 and the second is 26..

Comment: I said "since both given products are even."

Comment: Why does evenness of the given products allow us to assume that $y$ is even?  The possible solution $49$ (given by $x=22$, $y=1$, and $z=26$) is excluded not by the fact that the given products are even but only by the fact that 49 is not among the available choices.

Comment: @AndreasBlass You translated what I said to something false. I meant to say, since both products are even, in each one of the products, at least one of the variables must be even. Since this is multiple-choice, let's try a cheap approach. Specifically, let's see what happens if $y$ is even, in fact $2$. Why the downvote? I understand a downvote if it is the case that my answer was totally unclear and I'm not willing to change it. But if I am ready to elaborate and edit my post, there is no need for a downvote.